# How to get an instance or class at function body

Tags: javascript

I'm developing javascript library.

Want to get an instance or just class name at member function body dynamically without adding any properties.

I found that those code print like this.

```
 function Foo()
{
    this.var1 = 1;
    this.var2 = 2;
    this.print = function()
    {
        arguments.callee.prototype; // This shows "Foo.print {}".
    }
}

var myFoo = new Foo();
myFoo.print();
```

But I don't know how to get an instance `myfoo` or Class name `Foo` with that `prototype`. Is there any way?

And what that object instance means?

Comment: What's your actual goal? This looks more like something you're doing in order to do something else. If we knew what the *real* goal was, we could probably help better.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh sorry. I want to make a library which intercept function call stream. Catch a caller instance of function (Not the function, Actual instance that has caller function init.) So if there is another class Bar that has function B called myFoo.print(). I want to get a caller instance of Bar or just name of it to determine caller instance is itself or not at above position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store reference of `this` in a variable and use it in the function.

```js
 function Foo() {
   //Stor reference
   var _self = this;
   this.var1 = 1;
   
   this.print = function() {
     alert(_self.var1);
   }
 }

 var myFoo = new Foo();
 myFoo.print();
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. But I can't add any extra variable even in closure scope in this case. Is this only way to do that?